# Is there any way to remove specific view controller from UINavigationController's stack?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, stack

I want to remove a viewController from UINavigationController's stack.

is it possible? I found that UINavigationController.viewControllers is a type of NSArray, and it means I can't change.

I also know that I can change the stack(NSArray) with popViewController() or pushViewController(). How is it possible?

Can I change a specific viewController in UINavigationController to other viewController? or is there a way just remove a viewController from the stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
NSMutableArray * viewControllers = [ <<navController>>.viewControllers mutableCopy ]
[ viewControllers removeObject:<<viewControllerToRemove>> ] ;
navController.viewControllers = viewControllers ;
```

But this sounds "funny" to me--Can I ask why you want to implement this behavior?

Comment: Thanks!! After I test, I'll post why I'm doing this.

Comment: the [viewControllers mutableCopy] is <id> type, so I just cast this as NSMutableArray like this. [((NSMutableArray *)[viewControllers mutableCopy].... and I tried remove object at index 0. But I couldn't remove object. The [navigationController.viewControllers count] doesn't changed.

Comment: No need to cast. You can send any message to an `id`. What is viewControllers before and after?

Comment: Your code is missing an assignment - you create and amend the mutable copy without getting a pointer to it, so viewControllers itself is never modified. It should be NSMutableArray *newControllers = [[viewControllers mutableCopy...

Comment: ok I found why it didn't work. I tried to remove a ViewController before pushView animation completed. Thanks again!

Comment: This works for me, although Console spits out a warning:
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

Any way to suppress it? For me the reason to do this is to allow myself to reuse the same views while changing the interaction logic (e.g. from results view the user can go 'again' to the beginning of processing. i don't want them to end up in the previous results view, if they choose to back-back they should be at the beginning of the operation no matter how many times they repeated the actual processing view)